# Como alterar a cor de um fundo QTableView cabeçalho?

Tags: qt, background, background-color

Eu gostaria de saber como alterar a cor de fundo dos cabeçalhos ( horizontal / vertical) do objeto QTableWidget em Qt .

Eu já sei como alterar todos os cabeçalhos juntos, usando:

```
ui->tableWidget->setStyleSheet("QHeaderView::seção {background-color:red}");
```

Mas eu preciso mudar individualmente os itens. Obviamente, se isso é possível.

Comment: É possível utilizando Delegates, você precisa dar override na função `void paint();` utilizando o `QStyledItemDelegate` para implementar funções "personalizadas". Ou se for somente a cor de fundo, cada item do cabeçalho possui um `QTableWidgetItem`, que é o equivalente a uma célula, você pode alterar o `QPalette` de cada Item individualmente.

Answer (score -3):

QHeaderView:section{
background-color: rgb(0, 113, 170);
padding: 5px 5px 5px 0px ;
font-size: 12px;
font-family: "Arial";
font-weight: bold;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
border:none;
border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
}